# How can I condense this code in C#

Tags: c#

I want to know how to condense this working code. Its just for a simple game of go fish I made with a partner for our third day in C# class. This seems to be a ton of code for something Im sure can be condensed to a few lines.

C# code the part need help on

```
        int count1 = 0;
            int count2 = 0;
            int count3 = 0;
            int count4 = 0;
            int count5 = 0;
            int count6 = 0;
            int count7 = 0;
            int count8 = 0;
            int count9 = 0;
            int count10 = 0;
            int count11 = 0;
            int count12 = 0;
            int count13 = 0;
        // System.Console.WriteLine("HI THERE LOOK AT ME " + player1.numOfCardsInHand());
        for(int y = player1.numOfCardsInHand()-1; y >= 0 ; y--)
        {

            if(player1.getListObject()[y].val == 1)
            {
                count1++;
            }
            if(player1.getListObject()[y].val == 2)
            {
                count2++;
            }
            if(player1.getListObject()[y].val == 3)
            {
                count3++;
            }
            if(player1.getListObject()[y].val == 4)
            {
                count4++;
            }
            if(player1.getListObject()[y].val == 5)
            {
                count5++;
            }
            if(player1.getListObject()[y].val == 6)
            {
                count6++;
            }
            if(player1.getListObject()[y].val == 7)
            {
                count7++;
            }
            if(player1.getListObject()[y].val == 8)
            {
                count8++;
            }
            if(player1.getListObject()[y].val == 9)
            {
                count9++;
            }
            if(player1.getListObject()[y].val == 10)
            {
                count10++;
            }
            if(player1.getListObject()[y].val == 11)
            {
                count11++;
            }
            if(player1.getListObject()[y].val == 12)
            {
                count12++;
            }
            if(player1.getListObject()[y].val == 13)
            {
                count13++;
            }
            if(count1 == 4)
            {
                player1Points++;
                player1.getListObject().RemoveAll(u => u.Equals("1"));
            }
            if(count2 == 4)
            {
                player1Points++;
                player1.getListObject().RemoveAll(u => u.Equals("2"));
            }
            if(count3 == 4)
            {
                player1Points++;
                player1.getListObject().RemoveAll(u => u.Equals("3"));
            }
            if(count4 == 4)
            {
                player1Points++;
                player1.getListObject().RemoveAll(u => u.Equals("4"));
            }
            if(count5 == 4)
            {
                player1Points++;
                player1.getListObject().RemoveAll(u => u.Equals("5"));
            }
            if(count6 == 4)
            {
                player1Points++;
                player1.getListObject().RemoveAll(u => u.Equals("6"));
            }
            if(count7 == 4)
            {
                player1Points++;
                player1.getListObject().RemoveAll(u => u.Equals("7"));
            }
            if(count8== 4)
            {
                player1Points++;
                player1.getListObject().RemoveAll(u => u.Equals("8"));
            }
            if(count9 == 4)
            {
                player1Points++;
                player1.getListObject().RemoveAll(u => u.Equals("9"));
            }
            if(count10 == 4)
            {
                player1Points++;
                player1.getListObject().RemoveAll(u => u.Equals("10"));
            }
            if(count11 == 4)
            {
                player1Points++;
                player1.getListObject().RemoveAll(u => u.Equals("11"));
            }
            if(count12 == 4)
            {
                player1Points++;
                player1.getListObject().RemoveAll(u => u.Equals("12"));
            }if(count13 == 4)
            {
                player1Points++;
                player1.getListObject().RemoveAll(u => u.Equals("13"));
                }


            }
```

Comment: Google *csharp array*.

Comment: Array of counts and switch statement

Comment: could you point me toward an example of where I can see that

Comment: @DavidHollenbeck I believe it's a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com. After moving it there don't forget to specify details of `getListObject()` method

Comment: Ty ill look at it ty for the help

Comment: This smells to be a LINQ job

Comment: You should have put this on CodeGolf.StackExchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store cards count in the array with element for each card type. Use card type as index in cards array to increment counter or get current cards count of given type:

```
int[] cards = new int[13];
for(int i = player1.numOfCardsInHand() - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    int cardType = player1.getListObject()[i].val;
    cards[cardType - 1]++;

    if (cards[cardType - 1] == 4)
    {
        player1Points++;
        player1.getListObject().RemoveAll(u => u.Equals(cardType.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Though if you just want to get count of points (i.e. all four cards of given type) and see what will left in hand, then everything can be simplified to:

```
var fourOfType = player1.getListObject()
                        .GroupBy(c => c.val)
                        .Where(g => g.Count() == 4)
                        .Select(g => g.Key)
                        .ToList();

player1Points = fourOfType.Count;
foreach(var cardType in fourOfType)
    player1.getListObject().RemoveAll(c => c.Equals(cardType.ToString()))
```

Comment: Ty very much sorry for delay